# Unix hosts file order

Tags: linux, unix

For a long time I never even noticed but I made wrong /etc/hosts configuration on many machines. The order by the manual:

```
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   192.168.1.10    foo.example.org       foo
   192.168.1.13    bar.example.org       bar
   146.82.138.7    master.debian.org     master
   209.237.226.90  www.opensource.org
```

And what I did is:

```
   192.168.1.10    foo foo.example.org
```

Does this order really matters? Or is it some ancient unix feature back from the 80s?

Answer (score 4):

The `hosts` file is indeed an ancient thing [from the past](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952). However, as you can see in your own `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file, you still use it, and probably it has precedence over DNS.

The correct format of the `/etc/hosts` file is documented in the [`hosts(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html) manual page:

```
IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]
```

Comment: Would "foo" on it's own still get resolved to 192.168.1.10 in the OP's exmaple?

Comment: If you mean using `foo` as a FQDN, then yes.